# How to add nodejs in moodle?

Tags: node.js, plugins, moodle

I'm trying to develop a plugin in [moodle](https://moodle.org/plugins/) using nodejs, but i dont know how to include this nodejs in my plugin ?
Any comments or links or videos are appreciated.

Comment: What about webpack and use it in script tag ?

Comment: Im new in moodle, and in nodejs, webpack is not the best option to run nodejs in my plugin in moodle.

Comment: I tried adding a jquery in my moodle plugin before, but in nodejs setup i dont know how to do it. You can visit this link https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Javascript_Modules